# WebView slow scrolling

Tags: android, webview, scroll

For some reason the WebView I am using is quite slow, I don't have to much of a problem with the loading times for web pages, although if there is a way to improve that I would appreciate it. But my main concern is the jagged laggy scrolling. I'm reasonably sure there must be a way to get it working more smoothly, as other apps using (I assume) the WebView don't have this problem. I suppose it may be possible that these other apps are using some private web client although it seems to me very unlikely that all of them would. Others have asked similar questions on SO, but none of the answers are particularly effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to guess what your problem might be given the amount of information you have provided:

1. Did you declare that you want software rendering in your application's manifest (or by 
   setting the WebView's layer type)? Maybe try hardware mode.
2. What is the page that you're trying to load? Maybe there's tons of CSS/JavaScript going on there? Does a simpler page scroll well?
3. Which version of Android are you seeing this on, have you tried others? Maybe this is specific to a device?
4. Is the scroll not smooth (are you not hitting 60fps) or is there a large lag between the finger moving an the page moving? If it's the latter - maybe you have touch handlers slowing things down.

The above is just stuff from the top of my head. There are great articles out there on the topic, such [as this one](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/). Also, if you're using the Chromium WebView you can use the [profiling tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline) via [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging)

Comment: 1. Tried both 2. This happens with most webpages but yes as you would expect the less image intensive it is the less laggy 3. I have tried this on other devices, also the main device I use is the newest Nexus 7 so there's definitely no lack of hardware power 4. I have no custom touch handlers on the webView.

Comment: @timeshift117 - Can you load the HTML in Chrome - is it laggy there too or is it just the WebView? Also, any chance you could share a link to the HTML (or a link to you app?)

Comment: yeh I can probably send you a copy, but anyway, it is not any particular HTML or website that is laggy, but pretty much any site. Its definitely to do with the webView.

Comment: you can even see a very small, but still noticeable amount of lag when scrolling through search results of a google search

Comment: oh wow, i just changed the layer type and it started working. kind of strange seeing as I had tested that. oh well thats good, thanks for helping

Comment: @timeshift117 which layer type do you use, LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE?

Answer (score 6):

i think you have this code in your manifests

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

you have to delete if you have it.

Answer (score 2):

`webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);`

This work for me.

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?